# Trigger emails from Jenkins after validating a HTML Response

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a GET api URL ->  *http://{Project_IP}/{app_name}/ServiceQueueMonitorServlet?Action=retrieve* and from that I am getting a HTML Response :

```
 <TR> 
 <TD>Tag1</TD>
 <TD>502</TD>
 </TR>
 </table>

I need to trigger email when the value is greater than 100. 

I need to perform this using **Jenkins**. Please suggest if anyone has any thoughts on that.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jenkins DSL, you can use the [http request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/) plugin to send the API call:

```
def response = httpRequest "http://{Project_IP}/{app_name}/ServiceQueueMonitorServlet?Action=retrieve"
```

You can then use Groovy string manipulation ([doc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html)) to extract the number and send the email if the value is greater than 100.

If your HTML is too complex to use string manipulation for extraction, you can consider parsing the HTML in Groovy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion really , but is it possible to do other than using Groovy?

Comment: You mean without using DSL? By using a freestyle job? Or something else?

Comment: Yeah by susing DSL or Freestyle Job. Or may be by using Jenkins properties, if that is even possible.